# No such window error is shown for executing multiple instances in protractor

Tags: protractor, multiple-instances

I am trying to run my three specs in three separate instances but when I run the configuration file, one instance is opened and then closes. Other two specs runs successfully.

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
        var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
          dest: 'C:/Users/bill/report/report/screenshots',
           filename: 'my-report.html'
        });
        exports.config = {
            directConnect: true,
            framework: 'jasmine',
            // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            jasmineNodeOpts: {
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 640000000
        },
            specs: ['00-test.js',
            '01-test.js',
            '02-test.js'],
            multiCapabilities: [
            {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                shardTestFiles: true,
               maxInstances: 3,
            }
            ],
            // Setup the report before any tests start
            beforeLaunch: function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve){
                    reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
                });
            },
            // Assign the test reporter to each running instance
            onPrepare: function() {
                jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
            },
            // Close the report after all tests finish
            afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve){
                    reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
                });
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiCapabilities here as you are running in single browser which is chrome.Try Capabilities only.

Comment: Changed the multicapabilities to capabilities but still the issue is not fixed.